# on contextual keyword not mentioned in the c# keywords

Tags: c#, .net, keyword

on is a contextual keyword right? Sample : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx

It is not mentioned here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb(v=VS.100).aspx 
Or am I misinterpreting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is mentioned here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310804.aspx

Answer (score 1):

A [`Contextual keyword`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/the35c6y.aspx) is used to provide a specific meaning in the code, but it is not a [`reserved word`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx) in C#.

Its there on [`Contextual Keywords (C# Reference)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713588.aspx)

> The **on** contextual keyword is used in
>   the join clause of a query expression
>   to specify the join condition.